# Java: Raw use of parameterized class 'ArrayList'

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist, tuples

I have am android project I took over that that mixes Kotlin and Java, and I'm going through and converting all the Kotlin to Java, since our teams knows Java. The problem I'm running into is "Raw use of parameterized class 'ArrayList'. I can't figure out what class I'm supposed to pass to ArrayList<?> to get rid of the warning.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList amenities = new ArrayList<>();

amenities.add(MapsKt.hashMapOf(
   TuplesKt.to("ID", q.amenityID),
   TuplesKt.to("bExists", q.getAnswer().equals("1")),
   TuplesKt.to("Notes", Utils.CleanStringForUpload(q.amenityNotes))
));
```

Comment: Why you using Java's ArrayList but Kotlin's Map?

Comment: Each element represents an Amenity in an apartment inspection. Should I create a new amenity class for this? I have a TableAmenity, but it doesn't use the same fields.

Comment: You really should create a class with those fields instead of using a map. A map does not guarantee type safety, or that all the fields have values and correct ones.

Comment: @m0skit0: I converted it from Kotlin through Android Studio, and it doesn't do a perfect job. We are a java shop, and the kotlin is confusing some programmers, so I'm going through and converting it all to Java. Tools -> Kotlin -> Bytecode -> Decompile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `List<Map<String, Object>>` - the list contains maps (you're adding the result of invoking `hashMapOf`.

That map, then, seems to map Strings, such as `ID`, to a grab bag of weird stuff. This is a code smell and something that needs a refactor sooner rather than later - why don't you have something like:

```
class WhateverThisMightBe {
    String id;
    boolean exists;
    String notesHtml;
}
```

and then have a `List<WhateverThisMightBe>` instead? That is idiomatic java/kotlin. a `List<Map<String, Object>>` is trying to reinvent javascript/PHP in a very cruddy fashion in java. Not a good idea.

Comment: That's what I think I'm going to do Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the array element has to be `HashMap<String, Object>`. So you use `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` or even better: `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

But if `MapsKt.hashMapOf()` cannot deduce the most concrete type - just go with `ArrayList<Map<?,?>>` and be done with it.

Comment: Or even better: `List<Map<String, Object>>`.